# IE9 window.open problems

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am not sure what is going on but IE's window.open works **horribly**! 
I have a piece of javascript code that gets called from an angular controller that opens a second window (within same domain, popup blocked turned off) and tries to call a javascript method on that second window.

My code:

```
var newWindow = $window.open('somefile.html?' + Math.random(1000));                    
var fn = function () {                        
  //alert('I got called');
  newWindow.display($scope.mymsg);
}

if (newWindow.addEventListener)
  newWindow.addEventListener("load", fn, false);
else if (newWindow.attachEvent)
  newWindow.attachEvent("onload", fn);
else
  newWindow.onload = fn;
```

I need to support IE8 and IE9. I fiddled around with the code and got it work on IE8, but I cant get it to work on IE9. 
If I uncomment the alert, in IE9, i never see this. I have no idea why, since i am attaching the onload handler correctly. I am suspecting there is some sort of race condition, but if that was the case, I would have problems in the new window's display(), but it does not even get there because onload does not get called.

**UPDATE:**
So playing around with wrapping newly created window with jQuery helped a lot:

```
var newWindow = $window.open('somefile.html?z=' + Math.random(1000));
$(newWindow).load(function () { this.display($scope.mymsg); });
```

Also I added the dummy "z" param which I missed earlier. I almost have it working. 
Right now it seems like when you open this page for the first time, and quickly click the button to open second window, the second window opens up blank in IE8 (where it should have some messaged that were passed to it). But if you open the page and wait a couple of seconds the second window opens correctly displaying the passed in message. 
I also added a $(document).ready() in the second window's display() method. 
Another thing I did not mention before, but I think might have something to do with this, is that the whole mechanism which opens this window is wrapped inside a $q.all(). This is because before I open second window i make a call to save the data and return validation messages. I wonder if there is something going on with q, that is causing this race condition.

**UPDATE2:**
Moved the code to the last promise in the promise chain in $q. So right now it looks like this:

```
$q.all([
   //load data and put validate errors into $scope.mymsg
]).then(
   function () 
   {
     $(document).ready(function () {
       var newWindow = $window.open('somefile.html?z=' + Math.random(1000));
       $(newWindow).load(function () { this.display($scope.mymsg); });
     });        
   }, 
   function () 
   { 

   }
);
```

Issue still happening but a lot of less. It is definitely a race condition, but where I cannot figure it out. If you open certain pages and click on a button to open second window without waiting for page to fully load, it still might happen in certain random situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like when `fn` gets attached to the scripting sandbox of `newWindow`, then the `newWindow` *variable* in the parent is out of scope when `fn` actually gets executed there in the child.

Have you tried something like this in the parent:

```
popupParameters = {
    foo: 'bar'
};
```

and this in a `script` tag in the child:

```
popupParameters = window.opener.popupParameters;
alert(popupParameters.foo);
```

[`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.opener) should work in IE 8 and 9 ... I think.

Comment: So after all my research, the method above is the only one that works 100% of the time in IE8,IE9,Chrome and FF. Opening a window and trying to pass values into a function in the new window, works only sometimes in IE8/IE9 because of some unknown race conditions (or other things i cant figure out). The window always opens, but sometimes the onload function of new window does not get called. Reading values from opener seems to be the only way to have it working on the above listed browsers.

Comment: Verifying as well that this is the only fully cross browser solution. And, if you need to get a specific object by unique identifier, not a known named object, you can add query string parameters to the url and parse it out from location.href and do from the child window something like window.opener.lookupDictionary[passedParameter] and fetch the specific requested record.